# Getting 3D coordinates after multiplying by glMultMatrixd?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have a matrix stored in

```
GLdouble  m[16];
```

Now, using glMultMatrixd(m),I multiplied this matrix with 3d coordinates of a point. I want to know what are the new coordinates that are formed after multiplying with the matrix m. Is there any command in openGL that can do this?

Comment: This is really old, but anyway... 2 remarks: 1. glMultMatrix doesn't multiply matrix and point, it multiplies matrix and matrix, 2. you might want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202456/how-do-you-get-the-modelview-and-projection-matrices-in-opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any useful way.

In modern GL, the integrated matrix stack has been completely *removed*, for good reasons. Application programmers are reuired to write the own matrix functions, or use some existing library like [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/index.html) (which implements all of the stuff that used to be in old OpenGL in some header-only C++ library). It is worth noting in this context that operations like `glMultMatrix` never were GPU-accelerated, and were always carried out directly on the CPU by the GL implementation, so there is nothing lost by removing this stuff from the GL.

I'm not saying it would be impossible to somehow let OpenGL do that matrix * vector multiplication for you and to read back the result. The most direct approach for that would be to use [transfrom feedback](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback) to capture the results of the vertex shader in some buffer object. However, for transforming a single point, the overhead would be *exorbitant*.

Another - totally cumbersome - approach to get old GL with it's builtin matrix functions to calculate that product for you would be simply putting your point as the first column into a matrix, multiply that by using `glMultMatrix` to the matrix you set, read back the current matrix and find the transformed point in the first column of the resulting matrix.